# Joint Continuity and Separate Continuity in Topological rings

Tags: general-topology, continuity, topological-rings

I have been stuck with the following problem for quite some time, as I will next describe, by first introducing the definitions at hand. Here I have two definitions of joint continuity and two definitions of separate continuity. It is supposed to be easy to prove, but I am having trouble proving **claim 1** and **claim 2**. I would be grateful for any suggestions and happy to clarify any irregularities concerning the post

**Joint Continuity**

*J1* A binary operation $\beta: R \times R \rightarrow R$ defined for all $x,y \in R$ by $\beta(x,y)=x * y$ is said to be *jointly continuous* at $(x,y) \in R \times R$ if and only if for each neighbourhood $W$ of $x * y$, there exists a product of open sets $U \times V \subseteq R \times R$ containing $(x,y)$ such that $U*V \subseteq W$. If $\beta$ is jointly continuous at each point in $R \times R$ then $\beta$ is called (globally) jointly continuous.

*J2* Suppose that $X,Y$ and $Z$ are topological spaces. Let $f: X \times Y \rightarrow Z$ be a mapping. Then $f$ is called *jointly continuous* on $X \times Y$ if and only if the map $f$ is continuous from $X \times Y$, equipped with the product topology $\tau^{\times}$.

**Claim 1** In the event that $X=Y=Z$, we have equivalence for *J1* and *J2*.

**Separate Continuity**

*S1* A binary operation $\beta: R \times R \rightarrow R$ defined for all $x,y \in R$ by $\beta(x,y)=x * y$ is said to be *separately continuous* if and only if for all $a \in R$ and for all $U \in \mathcal{N}_0$ there exists $V \in \mathcal{N}_0$ such that $a*V \subseteq U; V*a \subseteq U$

*S2* Suppose $X,Y$ and $Z$ are topological spaces. Let $f: X \times Y \rightarrow Z$ be a mapping. Then $f$ is *separately continuous* on $X \times Y$ if and only if for all $(x_0,y_0) \in X \times Y$, both functions $x \mapsto f(x,y_0)$ and $y \mapsto f(x_0,y)$ are continuous on $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

**Claim 2** In the event that $X=Y=Z$, we have equivalence for *S1* and *S2*.

Comment: What is $\mathcal N_0$?

Comment: Hi Alex Ravsky. $\mathcal{N}_0$ is the collection of all neighbourhoods of $0$.

Comment: Then $S1$ means a separate continuity of $\beta$ at $(0,a)$ and $(a,0)$ provided $\beta(a,0)=\beta(0,a)=0$ for each $a\in R$.

Answer (score 1):

> **Claim 1** In the event that $X=Y=Z$, we have equivalence for *J1* and *J2*.

Implication $(J1 \Rightarrow J2)$ holds since $U\times V\in\tau^\times$ for each open subsets $U$ and $V$ of $R$. On the other hand, suppose that *J2* holds. Let $(R,\tau)$ be a topological space, $(x,y) \in R \times R$ be any point, and $W$ be any neighbourhood of $x*y$. By the definition of a neighborhood, there exists an open set $W’\ni (x,y)$ such that $W’\subseteq W$. *J2* implies that a set $\beta^{-1}(W’)$ is an open neighborhood of $(x,y)$. Since a family $\{ U \times V :U,V\in\tau \}$ is a base of the topology $\tau^\times$, there exist  $U,V\in\tau$ such that $(x,y)\in U \times V\subseteq  \beta^{-1}(W’)$. Then
$$U*V=\beta(U\times V) \subseteq \beta(\beta^{-1}(W’))\subseteq W’\subseteq W.$$

Comment: I don't think it is correct to say that $(x,y) \in W'$. Surely it should be $\beta(x,y) \in W'$